# Select the containing div of selected radio button

Tags: css, css-selectors

With the following markup:

```
<div class="paymentOption">
    <input type="radio" name="paymentOption" value="1" />
    <span class="marginLeft10">1-time payment using a different credit card</span>
</div>
```

**Using CSS only**, how do we select the div that contains a selected radio button? (is this *possible*?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently impossible with CSS. You can use jQuery though:

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/